# Modbus response, minimalmodbus

Tags: python, modbus

I'm using minimalmodbus to fetch the status of a device but it seems that the device gives me a byte too much, first byte is always x00, hence I'm not parsing the last one. Have also noticed that the device gives me x00 in the end aswell, but then using CAS in widows.

```
$ ./rstest.py 
minimalmodbus.Instrument<id=0xb6c844e0, address=4, mode=rtu, close_port_after_each_call=True, precalculate_read_size=True, debug=True, serial=Serial<id=0xb6c861d0, open=False>(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=19200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=2, timeout=0.1, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)>

MinimalModbus debug mode. Writing to instrument (expecting 6 bytes back): '\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\xfd\x9f'
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1415278843825.3 ms, minimum silent period: 2.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x00\x04\x01\x01\x01\x90' (6 bytes), roundtrip time: 15.6 ms. Timeout setting: 100.0 ms.
```

As you see, `\x00\x04\x01\x01\x01\x90`, should be `x04\x01\x01\x01\x90\x84`.

Anyway to strip and discard first byte?

EDIT: requested code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import minimalmodbus
import sys
minimalmodbus.CLOSE_PORT_AFTER_EACH_CALL = True
minimalmodbus.STOPBITS = 2

instr = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 04) #port, slaveadress

#instr.serial.echo = False
instr.serial.timeout = 0.1
instr.precalculate_read_size = True
instr.debug = True
instr.serial.baudrate = 19200
print instr
i = 0
c = 0
while i < 1:
    try:
        #temp = instr.read_register(2, 1, 4, signed=False)
        temp = instr.read_bit(0, functioncode=1)
        print 'OK!'
        print temp
        i = 100
    except ValueError:
        c = c + 1
        print 'Error number'
        print c 
        i = 1
    except IOError:
        c = c + 1
        print 'Error number'
        print c
        i = 1
```

Comment: Do you have any actual code?

Comment: Edited the post with test code

Comment: when I set precalc size to false I get \x00\x04\x01\x01\x01\x90\x84\x00 as I did in CAS